# Uncaught TypeError: Phaser.InputHandler is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

i want to apply mouse click events on a text below is my code,
i am using phaser3

```
var text = this.add.text(300, 400, "click and drag me", { font: "65px Arial", fill: "#ff0044", align: "center" });
text.input = new Phaser.InputHandler(text);
text.input.onOver.add(over, this);
text.input.onOut.add(out, this);
text.input.onDown.add(clicked, this);
function over(item) {}
function out(item) {}
function clicked(item) {}
```

at it throw error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Phaser.InputHandler is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you enable something for input in Phaser. Try looking at the [Input examples](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/category/input) or the [API Docs](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Sprite.html#inputEnabled). In short though, it's:

```
text.inputEnabled = true;
```

Comment: yes, i try it, it works in phaser 2.x but not in phaser 3

Comment: None of your code is Phaser 3 code, it's v2 code. There are equal examples showing how to do input for v3 too. You'd probably do well to study some of these: http://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=input/&q=

Comment: really, i am new in phaser, i follow the official example. anyway thank you :)